# Facebook Graph API + Videos endpoint - how to use content tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api

API/Endpoint: Graph/Video 
version: 2.8 / 2.6+
Question: Content Tags returns a set of numbers while the video reports downloaded off the UI returns a set of actual tags. Anyone know how to look up those numbers/ids for real tags?
Documentation has nothing mentioned about it as far as i could tell.
Thanks.
Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/

Comment: Just make an API request with the id you got …?

Comment: @CBroe What is the request format for content tags? Tried `/v2.12/1023278094369263`, but receiving a GraphMethodException `Unsupported get request. Object with ID ‘1023278094369263’ does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`